# Is Value-at-Risk translation invariant?

Tags: risk, value-at-risk, coherent-risk-measure

Let: $X=V_1-V_0R_0$ where $R_0$ is the interest rate. Then, is it so that this risk measure is Translation Invariant as:

$\textit{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)=\textit{VaR}_{\alpha}(V_1-V_0R_0)=V_0+\textit{VaR}_{\alpha}(V_1)=V_0+g(F^{-1}_{V_{1}}(\alpha))$?

Appreciate for anyone clarifying this.
Thanks

Comment: What is $g()$ above?

Comment: We have: $F^{-1}_{g(X)}(1-p)=g(F^{-1}(1-p))$

Comment: Still: how is $g()$ defined? What is it supposed to be. Is $g(x) =x^2$ ? $g$ just pops up in the last term, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation invariance of a risk measure $\rho$ is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_risk_measure) as
$$
\rho(X+k) =  \rho(X)-k,
$$
where $X$ is a random variable such that $\rho(X)$ exists and $k$ is a constant.
The meaning is that if I add an amount $k$ to my risky positions then the risk is reduced by this amount.

For VaR we consider the case that $X$ has a continuous distribution and that it is a profit and loss random varibale. Then
$$
VaR_\alpha(X) = -F^{-1}_{1-\alpha}(X)
$$
and
$$
P[-VaR_\alpha(X) \le X] = 1-\alpha.
$$
Note that $VaR$ is a posive number and e.g. for $\alpha=99\%$ the quantile $F^{-1}_{1-\alpha}(X)$ is a negative number.

It also holds that 
$$
P[-VaR_\alpha(X)+k \le X+k] = P[-VaR_\alpha(X) \le X] = 1-\alpha,
$$
and thus $VaR_\alpha(X+k) =  VaR_\alpha(X)-k$.

This is only true for elliptical distributions